# Set fields read-only according to type of user, using form_widget_args, Flask, SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

I have two types of users defined with different roles. In my model Example, I'd like field A to be read-only for user type **'staff'**, but editable for user type **'boss'**. Currently I'm only able to set the field read-only for all users. How to deal with this multiple user types circumstance?

```
class Example(Base_Model)
   __tablename__ = 'example'
   A = Column(Text(), nullable=False)

class View(Base_View)
    "form_widget_args": {
        "A": {"readonly": True}
    }

admin.add_view(View(Example, db.session))

## to check if the user is staff
# login.current_user.has_auth('staff')
```

Answer (score 1):

Override method `edit_form` ([docs](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.edit_form)), instance the default edit form, test who the user is and then modify the form as appropriate.

For example:

```
class ExampleView(AdminView):

    def edit_form(obj=None):
        form = super(ExampleView, self).edit_form(obj=obj)
        if current_user.has_auth('staff'):
            # untested
            form.A.render_kw['readonly'] = True
        return form
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if this also works for inline models? Like if my example model has a parent model, this would override the method for the parent model right?

Answer (score -1):

It has been a while working with Flask Admin, but would this work?

```
if "staff" in current_user.roles:
    "form_widget_args": {"A": {"readonly": True}
else:
    "form_widget_args": {"A": {"readonly": False}
```